# Complicated SQL query to find number difference in same table

Tags: sql

Could someone please help me write an SQL server query which would give me expected outcome from current data.I need to find meter Gap between each position.

[image: I need to find meter Gap between each position]

Comment: @Rams There is only one database so you call it anything you want to demonstrate how this could be done

Comment: How is Meter Gap Calculated?

Comment: Which RDBMS (You don't specify if this is Oracle, Sql Server, MySQL, Postgres, DB2, FoxPro, Teradata, Access, etc etc etc). It will make a difference in how one solves this.

Comment: @JNevill it's SQL server. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `LEAD` and combine it with `subquery` (reading table data once), like this

```
select tt.PersonId, tt.PreviousPosition, tt.NextPosition,
       tt.NextMeter - tt.previousMeter
  from (select PersonId, t.position PreviousPosition,
                LEAD(Position) OVER(order by Position) NextPosition,
                t.Meter PreviousMeter,
                LEAD(Meter) OVER(order by Position) NextMeter
           from myTable t) tt
 where tt.NextPosition is not null
```

but i have sorted by `Position`, if you have some key (which keep inserting ordering ) or you have some special logic with inerting and ordering use only that columns in sorting

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
SELECT id, position as previous,(
       SELECT TOP 1 position
       FROM table t1
       WHERE ti.position > t2.position
       ORDER BY
             position
       ) as next, 
       (
       SELECT TOP 1 meter
       FROM table t1
       WHERE ti.position > t2.position
       ORDER BY
             position
       ) - meter AS gap
FROM table t2
ORDER BY position
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I had to add a unique PK column to your data)

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    ID INT,
    PersonId INT,
    Position INT,
    Meter INT
)

INSERT INTO #Data VALUES (1,1,10,10),(2,1,22,20),(3,1,34,35),(4,1,46,46)

SELECT  PersonId,
        Position AS PreviousPosition,
        LEAD(Position) OVER (ORDER BY ID) NextPosition,
        Meter as ThisMeter,
        LEAD(Meter) OVER (ORDER BY ID) NextMeter
INTO    #Results
FROM    #Data

SELECT PersonId,
       PreviousPosition,
       NextPosition,
       NextMeter - ThisMeter AS MetreGap
FROM   #Results
WHERE  NextPosition IS NOT  NULL

DROP TABLE #Results
DROP TABLE #Data
```